# validateField client event doen't work properly in Chrome

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm trying to validate  'vatregnumber' field  on the Vendor record,
Here is my sample code.  It works in Mozilla but in Chrome it messages infinite loop.

```
function clientValidateField(type, name, linenum) {
    if (name === 'vatregnumber') {
        var isValid = validateTaxNum();  // a function returns boolean. If it returns false it gives an alert message. //
        return isValid;
    }

    return true; 
}
```

I agree that this similar question has been asked, but is there any way to slove these kind of troubles

Comment: You have the `return true;` statement outside of both `if` blocks - is this what you want?  Not sure whether it could cause the issue you're talking about, but if I understand what you're trying to do, you should have the `return true;` just before the last closing brace `}` otherwise it will return true on every other field too.

Comment: yeah, you are right. I tried as you said, but  anything is changed, same inifinite message's occurs

Comment: That code should not create a loop. I've done lots of validation that works across browsers. Can you paste all of your code? Or at least the entire validation function? Do any other functions call the validate function?

Comment: @bknights I cheked in Mozilla, it  works as expected, I think there is no problem with the client script. Here is my code .                                       `function clientValidateField(type, name, linenum) {

 if (name === 'vatregnumber') {
  var isValid = validateTaxNum();  // a function returns boolean. If it returns false, it gives an alert message. //
  return isValid;

 }

 return true;

}`

Comment: Do you have any other client scripts running?

Comment: yes, except it, I'm using validateLine and SaveRecord  functions on the same form

Comment: I just came across [this question and comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43268980/netsuite-suitescript-why-does-this-validate-field-script-enter-an-infinite-l); saying it's an issue in Chrome 57.

Comment: @Krypton,  yeah the cause is Chrome defect, i think